# Why does FHS have a usr directory

Tags: linux, fhs

It appears you can put all you need in /bin so why do we bother with the /usr/bin directory?

Comment: This is perfectly reasonable question for SO; the fact that two close votes choose two different alternative sites is indicative of something.

Comment: This is an excellent question.

Comment: Where are the close votes depicted?

Comment: You need 3k rep to vote and view http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/bin` is supposed to reside on the root filesystem, whereas `/usr` may be an alternate filesystem - even network mounted (multiple boxes sharing the same `/usr`).

This means that any essential basic utilities you need to bring up the system and mount filesystems, including troubleshooting, should live in `/bin`.  Everything non-essential can go in `/usr`.

Comment: Ah, now it's clear. I knew that it was not for naught that such a design was conceived.

Comment: Can you link to the FHS doc for this?

Comment: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#PURPOSE3 for /bin and http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#PURPOSE18 for /usr.